# vb.net connection entity framework connection string security

Tags: vb.net, winforms, connection-string, app-config, ado

I understand the possibilities for encrypting a connection string in .net v4. I have a win forms  application that will be used by multiple people on different machines. I understand that I need to protect the connection string at time of the app being first run on the target machine. However I am concerned that for a period of time my connection string will be unencrypted. I am looking for advice in how to deploy my app with the connection string already encrypted or encrypted during installation.

How would anyone else go about encrypting the connection string in a secure way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it OK if the people that are allowed to use the application see the connection string? Or should it be kept secret even from them?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Please leave a comment when downvoting. It seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your connectionString config section and [modify it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Configuration_File.aspx), like that:

```
oSection = oConfiguration.GetSection("connectionStrings") as System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection;

if (oSection != null)
{
    if ((!(oSection.ElementInformation.IsLocked)) && (!(oSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked)))
    {
        if (protect)
        {
            if (!(oSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected))
            {
                blnChanged = true;

                // Encrypt the section.
                oSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection
                            (strProvider);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (oSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                blnChanged = true;

                // Remove encryption.
                oSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
            }
        }
    }

    if (blnChanged)
    {
        // Indicates whether the associated configuration section 
        // will be saved even if it has not been modified.
        oSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

        // Save the current configuration.
        oConfiguration.Save();
    }
}
```

[Example in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EncryptingTheAppConfig.aspx):

```
Public Sub ProtectSection()
    ' Get the current configuration file.
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
                    (ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim protectedSection As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection(m_Section)

    ' Encrypts when possible
    If ((protectedSection IsNot Nothing) _
    AndAlso (Not protectedSection.IsReadOnly) _
    AndAlso (Not protectedSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected) _
    AndAlso (Not protectedSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked) _
    AndAlso (protectedSection.SectionInformation.IsDeclared)) Then
        ' Protect (encrypt)the section.
        protectedSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(Nothing)
        ' Save the encrypted section.
        protectedSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can use this code during the installation for your application (to check, is the config protected) and you can check every time during runnig your application.

**UPDATE:**
About your question from comments - you can distribute your application with empty connection string, and during your install, set this property (do not forget about code obfuscation in this case) and save your config file.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Slightly off topic but what type of installer would you use to distribute an app that would use the installer to protect the connection string? Thanks